# League of Legends no longer available at Playonlinux?

Tags: playonlinux

Tried to reinstall Playonlinux, but it still doesn't appear even at its latest version (4.2.10) Isn't it available now?

Answer (score 0):

Because the script is outdated and probably wont work , but there is a beta script for it , for more information you can look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/League_of_Legends).